# How do I implement an application similar to google maps on android?

Tags: android, maps

I have a couple of images on available to my program. They are parts of jigsaw puzzle (with rectangular pieces though). I wanted the look and feel similar to that of google maps in android.

One way I could implement was to create a set of ImageViews and keep recycling them, as the user pans the image in any direction. However, to me that appears like a brute force method. Is there any alternative approach to implement such kind of application?

Or rather how is google maps implemented? A set of Imageviews ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for your case the OpenGL route might be the best choice.  You can get started with the [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html).

Comment: SurfaceView was made for this type of thing!

Answer (score 0):

Using set of images and recycling them is a valid method. But you can enhance it by adding some redundant ones to keep close to view area images preloaded.